# Implementing a Shell Sort algorithm on a Linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, linked-list, shellsort

I am doing a project for my Data Structures class where I must implement a Shell Sort algorithm on a Linked List. We did this previously using an Array List, and when given an input of 10,000 random integers, it took my program an average of 0.012 seconds to sort the list. Now that I have implemented that same algorithm using a Linked List DS that I made it averages around 20.1 seconds (yikes). I'm wondering whether this is normal, or if it has something to do with the implementation itself? Here's the main portion of the algorithm, using Knuth's sequence as the gap values:

```
while(k >= 1) {
            for (int i = k; i < theList.size(); i++) {
                int j = i;
                while (j >= k && theList.get(j - k).compareTo(theList.get(j)) > 0) {  
                    T smaller = theList.delete(j);
                    theList.add(j - k, smaller);

                    T larger = theList.delete(j - k + 1);
                    theList.add(j, larger);

                    j -= k;
                }
            }
```

I tried using a swap method to swap the two values being compared and that didn't seem to do much. I also tried refactoring my get(), add(), and delete() methods for the LinkedList but that didn't really do anything either.

Comment: What is the time complexity of each of the list operations used by your sort, on ArrayList and your linked list respectively?

Comment: `get` on a linked list is inefficient, as well as other methods that need an *index*. Use iterators.

Comment: The time complexity for the list operations are about what you except from both lists. Get is O(1) for array list and O(n) for linked list. delete() on my linked list is O(n), same as add(). For the arraylist implementation its O(1) to swap two indexes. Im guesing thats why my Linked List version is so inneficient, I just dont know if its normal to go from 0.01 seconds to 20 seconds.

Comment: I'm guessing that the get() method is what's really slowing it down, as I access the same index numerous times with get(), delete(), and add() on the linked list, as opposed to O(1) with array list indexing and swaping elements.